# Bronze, Silver and Gold Commitment Badges

Tags: feature-request, area-51, badge-request

After completing a commitment for a SE site my interest starts to wane. I find I only visit when I need answers and not to interact with the community like I used to.

I think Bronze, Silver and Gold versions of a *Commitment* badge would help reduce the malaise. I'm not talking about the completed commitments badges:

- Upholder
- Adherent
- Loyalist

It would have to be site specific, so something more like a the [Tag Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) on SO.

Comment: Personally, I think the on-site chat rooms are a great way to build a community. However, this isn't suited for each type of site...

Comment: Don't SE sites have tag badges, too? Why don't they fulfill the same role you say they fill on SO?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you mention SO's tag badges; why wouldn't this hypothetical other SE site's tag badges have the same effect?

That said, -1 primarily because it seems to me that these badges would just delay the problem. What happens after users earn Loyalist? What'll keep them on the site then?

I would say that a user who's only in it for the A51 rep or some badges should just stop. It doesn't help a site much to have users who are only going through the motions of participating. Granted, in the short term, they'll give the impression that there's activity on the site, but their questions and answers are likely to be of below-average quality. And in the long term, these people will drop off and contribute to ghost-town-itis.

Comment: I tend to agree.. if the badges and rep on *the site itself* don't do it for you.. time to move on.